# Using asynchronous sockets for server handling multiple clients

Tags: c, windows, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have developed a single server multiple client udp application using multithreading. I want to switch to a single processor system now so multithreading will no more help me :(

Now I want to implement the server using **asynchronous sockets** so that it may be able to handle multiple clients at a time.

Will this approach work fine? Is it correct to use asynchronous socket if you want to handle multiple clients using one single server? 
Is using asynchronous socket a better approach than using threads for handling multiple clients?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to take a look at libevent: http://www.libevent.org/ it provides all necessary functions to organize asynchronous servers.

Comment: This is correct. If you need, there are many other libraries that do much the same: ZeroMq, RabbitMq, Boost.asio, etc. These are all signaled meaning that they take very little CPU and can service thousands of simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 1):

You could multithread the server just as well as make it asynchronous. Unless you have a *LOT* (100s/1000s) of connections you probably won't notice the performance difference of any of the approaches to multiplexing your connections. select/poll, threading, aio will all perform about the same for a low number of connections. aio is harder to implement solidly though.

Comment: Possibly. I think it's harder to get your head round and design for, but that's a personal opinion. Unless you need to support a high number of connections (or you're just technically interested) I would go for the approach you feel most comfortable with; performance is unlikely to be an issue, whereas complicated design, bugs, time-to-market and maintenance are more likely to be!